# Javascript className property only updates alternate list items

Tags: javascript

I tried the following code :

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("cc");
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i].className = "cd";
}
```

```css
.cc {
  background-color: blue;
}

.cd {
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="cc">A</li>
  <li class="cc">B</li>
  <li class="cc">C</li>
  <li class="cd">D</li>
</ul>
```

This only updates the alternate list items and not all of them having the same class. I would like to know the reason why this isn't working.

Answer (score 6):

### Issue

`.getElementsByClassName()` is causing the issue. See below.

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("cc");
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  console.log(`----- Loop ${i} -----`);
  // Current HTML collection
  console.log(a);
  // Target element
  console.log(`Target: ${a[i].textContent}`);
  a[i].className = "cd"; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="cc">A</li>
  <li class="cc">B</li>
  <li class="cc">C</li>
  <li class="cd">D</li>
</ul>
```

**How your for loop works:**

1. `a = [A, B ,C]`
2. `a[0] = A` -> `A.className = 'cd'`
3. `a = [B, C]`
4. `a[1] = C` -> `C.className = 'cd'`
5. `a = [B]`
6. `a[2] = undefined` -> loop ends

### Solution

Use `.querySelectorAll()` instead of `.getElementsByClassName()`.
The former yields a static collection and the latter is [dynamic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) (meaning that as you update the DOM, the collection itself is updated as well).

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll(".cc");
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i].className = "cd";
}
```

```css
.cc {
  background-color: blue;
}

.cd {
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="cc">A</li>
  <li class="cc">B</li>
  <li class="cc">C</li>
  <li class="cd">D</li>
</ul>
```

### Modern solution

Use `.forEach()` instead of `for` loop.

```js
const a = document.querySelectorAll('.cc');
a.forEach(element => element.className = 'cd');
```

```css
.cc {
  background-color: blue;
}

.cd {
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="cc">A</li>
  <li class="cc">B</li>
  <li class="cc">C</li>
  <li class="cd">D</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your edit, Xaniff. Your explanation is much better than my original one.

Answer (score 0):

here the solution. the explanation you can find here: [How can I change an element's class with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-can-i-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("cc");
while (a.length > 0) {
  a[0].className = 'cd';
}
```

```css
.cc {
  background-color: blue;
}

.cd {
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="cc">A</li>
  <li class="cc">B</li>
  <li class="cc">C</li>
  <li class="cd">D</li>
</ul>
```